# Meta analysis of control groups

Tags: meta-analysis

I am conducting systematic review to establish control value of a new diagnostic variable (continuous data). I would like to do sub-group analysis as well. Since it is only for control group, is meta-analysis for single arm studies suitable for this? As far as I understood, single-arm meta analysis is usually used for treatment group and not for control group. If meta-analysis is not suitable, what would you suggest?
What software that you can suggest to perform this task? (preferably a user-friendly one)

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is perfectly possible to do this. Effectively this is a meta-analysis of observational studies with all the advantages and disadvantages that entails. Without knowing your definition of user-friendly recommending software is problematic. There are certainly several options in R and people also use Stata routines.